# indexPathForCell unrecognized selector sent to instance on iOS 8 with ObjC

Tags: uitableview, ios8, unrecognized-selector, nsindexpath

I have a UITextField in UITableViewCell. When user tries to enter some text into this textfield, app scrolls that cell to the top of UITableView.Here is the code:

```
#pragma mark - UITextField Delegates
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    UITableViewCell *QCELL = (UITableViewCell *)[[[[textField superview]superview]superview]superview];
    UITableView *QTable = (UITableView *)[[QCELL superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath*path = = [QTable indexPathForCell:QCELL];
    return true;
}
```

and exception

```
    2014-09-11 11:12:50.604 InspectTHIS[9401:348011] -[UIView indexPathForCell:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c2e8b30
    2014-09-11 11:12:50.608 InspectTHIS[9401:348011] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView indexPathForCell:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c2e8b30'
```

## Updated - Answered

After I search in Views Layer I found this

////////// iOS 8 //////////

```
<UIView: 0x792aabd0; frame = (0 0; 768 1023); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x792aac40>>
<UITableViewCellContentView: 0x79758340; frame = (0 0; 768 699); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers =                 <NSArray: 0x79758530>; layer = <CALayer: 0x797583b0>>
<QuestionCell: 0x79757ed0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 768 699); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x79758190>>
<UITableViewWrapperView: 0x7967bc50; frame = (0 0; 768 750); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7967bef0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7967be30>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {768, 750}>
<UITableView: 0x78c99600; frame = (0 244; 768 750); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7967b9c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7967ae00>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {768, 699}>
<UIView: 0x7967abd0; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7967ac40>>
```

//////// iOS 7 ////

```
<UIView: 0x11fbbbf0; frame = (0 0; 768 1023); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x11fbbc50>>
<UITableViewCellContentView: 0x11f832a0; frame = (0 0; 768 699); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers =     <NSArray: 0x11f8dd40>; layer = <CALayer: 0x11faa6f0>>
<UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x11fc4090; frame = (0 0; 768 699); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x11f9c830>; layer = <CALayer: 0x11f978f0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
<QuestionCell: 0x11fa2090; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 768 699); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x11fa1c90>>
<UITableViewWrapperView: 0xced1860; frame = (0 0; 768 750); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xced18d0>>
<UITableView: 0xd958800; frame = (0 244; 768 750); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xced1560>; layer = <CALayer: 0xced0eb0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
<UIView: 0xced0c30; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xced0c90>>
```

as you can see in iOS 8, UITableViewCellScrollView is missing and and I can't go up like I did in iOS 7. so i change the code like this.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSIndexPath*path;
    UITableView *QTable;
    CGFloat version =[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
    if (version >= 7.0)
    {
        UITableViewCell *QCELL = (UITableViewCell *)[[[[textField superview]superview]superview]superview];
        QTable = (UITableView *)[[QCELL superview] superview];
        path  = [QTable indexPathForCell:QCELL];
    }
    else if(version >= 8.0)
    {
        UITableViewCell *QCELL = (UITableViewCell *)[[[textField superview]superview]superview];
        QTable = (UITableView *)[[QCELL superview] superview];
        path  = [QTable indexPathForCell:QCELL];
    }

    NSIndexPath*path = = [QTable indexPathForCell:QCELL];
    return true;
}
```

Comment: If the text field is within the text view cell then shouldn't `QCELL` be simply `[textField superview]`?

Comment: i test the above example , it doesn't work

Comment: @wod what seems to be the problem ?

Comment: for iOS 8 if the textfield is within the cell, QCELL should be [textField superview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly I had a button inside a UITableViewCell.This will work for you. Here buttonView means my UIButton instance
For iOS 8

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[buttonView superview];
```

gave me the UITableViewCell instance
and for iOS 7 as usual

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [buttonView superview]superview];
```

gave me the UITableViewCell instance

And the

> [QTable indexPathForCell:cell];

Will give you the NSIndexPath(This part is ok in the given answer).

Answer (score 2):

I change your original code a little and came out with this:

I made this change because I had a problem when the version was 8 the if for the >= 7 was been fired. And I need the variables outside the if.

```
 CGFloat version =[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
UITableViewCell *cell;
UITableView *table;

if ((version > 7) && (version < 8))
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[[[sender superview] superview]superview];
    table = (UITableView *)cell.superview.superview;


}
else if(version > 8)
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[[sender superview] superview];
    table = (UITableView *)cell.superview.superview;

 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I was having the same problem with those if statement. Now it looks like this

if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
...
}else if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
...
}

Where #define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you get for traversing the view hierarchy instead of using delegate methods from the cell itself.

Make the Cell itself respond to the delegate of the textview. Let the cell have it's own protocol (delegate methods), and let your TableViewController be it's delegate.

Then your code in the subclassed UITableViewCell-class will look something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{

    [self.delegate textFieldDidBeginEditingForCell:self];
    return true;
}
```

Then in your TableViewController:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditingForCell:(YourCustomCell*)cell 
{
    NSIndexPath *path =  [QTable indexPathForCell:cell];

   ...
}
```